# OpenDKIM not signing e-mails from host10.example.com

Tags: dkim, opendkim

I have a server, called `host10.example.com` which sends administrative e-mails by `mailx` commands to myself only.  These outgoing e-mails need to be signed by OpenDKIM.  I have tried many configurations for several hours but OpenDKIM never signed anything.  Once every 10 times or so a header line by OpenDKIM is added to the e-mail but nothing is ever signed.

I have added the selector `host10` in the DNS zone of `example.com` with a valid public key.  The private key was generated by

```
# opendkim-genkey -b 4096 -d example.com -s host10 -D /etc/opendkim/keys/
```

and resides in `/etc/opendkim/keys/host10.private`.  It is readable by the `opendkim` group:

```
# ls -ld /etc/opendkim /etc/opendkim/* /etc/opendkim/keys/*
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root opendkim 4096 Dec 10 16:43 /etc/opendkim
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root       20 Dec  9 12:24 /etc/opendkim/default.private -> keys/host10.private
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root       16 Dec  9 12:24 /etc/opendkim/default.txt -> keys/host10.txt
drwxr-x---. 2 root opendkim 4096 Dec 10 01:47 /etc/opendkim/keys
-rw-r-----. 1 root opendkim 3247 Dec  9 12:23 /etc/opendkim/keys/host10.private
-rw-r-----. 1 root opendkim  850 Dec  9 12:23 /etc/opendkim/keys/host10.txt
-rw-r-----. 1 root opendkim  630 Dec 10 16:27 /etc/opendkim/KeyTable
-rw-r-----. 1 root opendkim 1484 Dec 10 16:43 /etc/opendkim/SigningTable
-rw-r-----. 1 root opendkim  480 Dec 10 14:48 /etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
```

**Current configuration** (with commented out artifacts from previous trials):

#### 1. Postfix

Added this to `/etc/postfix/main.cf`

```
# DKIM signing by opendkim via milter
milter_protocol = 6
milter_default_action = accept
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
```

#### 2. OpenDKIM

Main configuration `/etc/opendkim.conf`

```
## BASIC OPENDKIM CONFIGURATION FILE
## See opendkim.conf(5) or /usr/share/doc/opendkim/opendkim.conf.sample for more

PidFile /var/run/opendkim/opendkim.pid
Mode    v
Syslog  yes
SyslogSuccess   yes
LogWhy  yes
UserID  opendkim:opendkim
Socket  inet:8891@localhost
Umask   002
SendReports no
SoftwareHeader  yes
Canonicalization    relaxed/relaxed
Selector    host10
MinimumKeyBits  1024
KeyFile /etc/opendkim/keys/host10.private
KeyTable    refile:/etc/opendkim/KeyTable
SigningTable    refile:/etc/opendkim/SigningTable
OversignHeaders From
QueryCache  yes
```

Here is `/etc/opendkim/SigningTable`

```
# OPENDKIM SIGNING TABLE

* host10._domainkey.example.com 
*@host10.example.com host10._domainkey.example.com 
*@example.com host10._domainkey.example.com 

example.com host10._domainkey.example.com  
host10.example.com host10._domainkey.example.com
```

This is `/etc/opendkim/KeyTable`

```
# OPENDKIM KEY TABLE

# host10._domainkey.example.com host10.example.com:host10:/etc/opendkim/keys/host10.private
host10._domainkey.example.com example.com:host10:/etc/opendkim/keys/host10.private
# host10._domainkey.example.com example.com:host10:/etc/opendkim/keys/host10.private
```

#### Test

Mails are sent like this:

```
# echo Thanks | mailx -s Test test@example.org
```

which sends mails as `root@host10.example.com` and I also tested

```
# echo Thanks | mailx -s Test -r host10@example.com test@example.org
```

Comment: Is it possible to get a log file entry for one of the test sends?

Comment: @tsc_chazz The messages are sometime non-existent, sometimes I get `no signing domain match for host10.example.com` and `no signing subdomain match for ...` from `systemctl status opendkim`.

Answer (score 0):

It was mainly this line which kept OpenDKIM from signing outgoing e-mails:

Main configuration `/etc/opendkim.conf`

```
Mode    v
```

This default setting on my system meant that OpenDKIM would "v" - "verify" e-mails but not sign.

In order to sign outgoing e-mails the line needs to be changed to

```
Mode     s
```

or to both sign outgoing e-mails and verify incoming ones (not in my use case)

```
Mode     sv
```

I had seen "v" and "sv" somewhere in examples before but since these are cryptic letters without context I had not made the connection to signing yes/no and verifying yes/no.  So perhaps not a very intuitive configuration file design, especially since the other options do have meaningful names and values.  Cost me many hours.  Hope this will at least help someone else.